# how to understand this pointer with array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, memory-address

```
int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
struct timeval stamp;
if (skb->stamp.tv_sec == 0)
do_gettimeofday(&skb->stamp);
}
```

I want to get the time when which the kernel starts executing the above function and finally I want to store it in a buffer skbuf. If i code like above then is it possible to store the scheduling time in buffer ? please someone help me in this ? My question - if i call sched_clock(); then it will give the scheduling time of the system but how to store it in a buffer finally ? Is it possible to use structure pointer to store the values from scheduling clock ?

Comment: `sched_clock` doesn't take an argument.

Comment: yes !! thats true. but how to store it in a skbuf ??

Comment: Don't you mean `sk_buff`? I can't find `struct skbuff` in the Linux kernel.

Comment: you can find : int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb) in /linux/net/core/dev.c

Comment: the above api is the receiver side api, which receives the data from the sender. I want to calculate the time when it receives the data and store it in a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
__net_timestamp(skb);
```

I found this function in http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/skbuff.h

```
static inline void __net_timestamp(struct sk_buff *skb)
 {
         skb->tstamp = ktime_get_real();
 }
```

Comment: you can find : int netif_rx(struct sk_buff *skb) in /linux/net/core/dev.c. 
the above api is the receiver side api, which receives the data from the sender. I want to calculate the time when it receives the data and store it in a buffer. could you please help me ??

Comment: Isn't that what my code does? I'm not a kernel programmer, I just searched for `sched_clock` in the Linux source, this is my best guess.

Comment: what is that sb->tv64 in your code ?? where should i look for sched_clock structure ??

Comment: thank you. after modifying the kernel then what are the command to boot the kernel ??

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the time when which the kernel starts executing the above function and finally I want to store it in a buffer skbuf.

```
int getsocketschedtime(stuct skbuf *sb)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL); 
    sb->tstamp.off_sec = tv.tv_sec;
    sb->tstamp.off_usec = tv.tv_usec;
    // ... do smth useful
}
```

Comment: gettimeofday is same as timestmap ?? I want a timestamp.

Comment: "gettimeofday is same as timestmap ??" -- yep, gettimeofday return timestamp (via reference &tv).

Comment: @OlegTrakhman Is `gettimeofday` available in the kernel? His code is in a network driver.

Comment: @Barmar : gettimeofday is available in kernel.

Comment: I must admit i'm not into networking/sockets; I've just seen that  struct skb_timeval and struct timeval are similar, althoug their names, and more important their field names (off_sec vs tv_sec) suggest they may have different purposes. Be careful, and as usual, RTFM :)

Comment: after modifying the kernel then what are the command to boot the kernel ??

Comment: @OlegTrakhman: if i want to store the only timestamp of millisecond in buffer then what should i do in the above code ?? I dont want micro and seconds in the buffer.